# Query with subquery in Entity Framework Core - WHERE EXISTS IN

Tags: c#, subquery, entity-framework-core

I have two queries in Entity Framework Core 2.1. I believe it is possible to write it as single query:

```
Guid accountId == ....

Guid[] connIds = context.ConnectionAccount
       .Where(connSub => connSub.Account== accountId)
       .Select(connSub => connSub.connectionId)
       .ToArray();

var query = context.connection
          .Where(conn => connIds.Contains(conn.Id))
          .Select(conn => new
           {
            conn.Id,
            conn.Username,
            ...
           })
           .ToArray();
```

Comment: don't materialize the query `connIds` to array and pass it as IQueryable in second one to see if that works

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm.

Comment: great, cheers (Y)